# how to know controller is presentModalViewController in or pushViewController in?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

The view controller may got by pushViewController or presentModalViewController from super view controller. In this view controller how should I know which way the controller from? I need it to close the view --

```
if (presentModalViewController ) {
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }else{
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

self.navigationController will be nil if the view is not in a nav controller (for example because it was presented).  Of course if you present and have a nav controller, you'll need to dig deeper.

Additionally "self.presentingViewController" may be nil if you were not presented.

Note a common idiom for iOS is to create a simple protocol to handle closing the view.  The view that pushes/presents is the delegate and gets their "viewWantsToClose" target called.  If you create a new Utility project, you'll see what I'm talking about.  This is how Apple flips the "info" view closed.  You could potentially let your view accept a block for the "doCloseAction".

Comment: I tried, no matter, presented or not self.navigationController is not nil. may be because I present controller like this `UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:userAlbumListViewController];
        [self.viewController presentModalViewController:nc animated:YES];`  ?

Comment: @Jason, yup, if you do that you will have a nav controller.  The "proper" way to solve this issue is by using the target-action pattern (or update that to pass in an 'onCloseBlock').  You want your VC figure out it's surroundings, and that will work - but it will be a tad fragile - and YOU must be aware hierarchy options and write the appropriate close code.  As noted, you can check those 2 values, and possibly some other things - but I think you'll be happy if you bite the bullet and do this via a block.

Answer (score 0):

You are responsible for pushing or presenting a view so you should know when to pop or dismiss a view. If you still have to perform this kind of check, you can verify from the child view if `self.navigationController` is nil or not

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
if (self.navigationController == nil) {
      //[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; //Deprecated in iOS 6.0
      [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}else{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

or

```
NSArray* views = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
if (self.navigationController == nil || self == [views objectAtIndex:0])
{
   //In the root view of navigationController or a presented View.
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}else{
   [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: no!! if it's nill you can not pop cuz there's no navigation controller so we dismiss the view controller. else is if the navigation controller exist then we can pop our view.

Comment: I tried, no matter, presented or not self.navigationController is not nil. may be because I present controller like this `UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:userAlbumListViewController];
        [self presentModalViewController:nc animated:YES];`  ?

Comment: uha, you should check if you are in the root of the UINavigationController,, check my Edit...